# javascript validation not working for only alphabetic values

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have used a javascript validation function to validate it. I've used it to see whether the text entered to the html textbox is alphabetic(No numeric characters allowed). The function is called during onkeyup and onblur. The only problem is even when numeric values or special characters are typed in the validation doesn't work. If I leave the field blank then it works(Displays that the field is left blank). Here's my javascript code:

```
function isAlphabetic(x,y){
    var exp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/; 
    var a = document.getElementById(y).value;
    if(a=="" || a== null){
            document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "You cannot leave this feild empty"; 
                return;
    }
    else if(a!="" && a!= null){
        if(y.match(exp)){
            document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "Only enter alphabetic characters allowed";
            return;
        }

    }
    else{
        return;
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `y` as an id of element, I suppose you shouldn't check it with your regexp. Instead you should check `a`:

```
if(a.match(exp)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript anymore for any of this. Use the [pattern attribute](https://developers.whatwg.org/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute) on the input field and the browser won't let the user enter anything that doesn't match, and use `required` to prevent submitting the form with an empty value.

Also, do you really want only ASCII letters? (are spaces allowed? how about non-ASCII letters such as "é"?)

Comment: Does the pattern attribute compatible with old browsers? And yeah only ASCII values including spaces

Comment: No, it's modern HTML so it won't work in older browsers (http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern). Unless you're working in an obsolete corporate environment, that's not a problem.